# Why does a bounty suspend topicality?

Tags: discussion, bounty

There is [a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/are-revenue-or-profit-sharing-considered-nondiscretionary-bonuses-when-determini) that to me appears to be appears to be clearly off-topic in that it deals with regulations and legal matters. The name alone tells one that:

> Are revenue or profit sharing considered nondiscretionary bonuses when determining the salary base in the FLSA “Final Rule” overtime exemption rules?

I attempted to nominate for closure but am prevented from doing so because it has a bounty for the next 3 days.

Why does putting a bounty on a question prevent the topicality guidelines from being enforced?

Comment: This doesn't answer your actual question, but I don't believe that question would be considered off-topic. It falls under the category of being legal, but something that your typical HR person should know the answer to. See [this Meta answer](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1861/16983) for more discussion on the topic of how much 'legal' is allowable.

Comment: Turnabout is fair play. I had this happen to a question I considered off-topic a few months ago. :) Suffice to say that I wouldn't put a bounty on a question I'd consider off-topic and I'm basing that on the meta answer @DavidK linked.

Comment: Fully agree with David K, a competent local HR manager would be able to answer this without consulting their lawyer.  If only the community would uphold the same standards when local≠US.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this question has already asked over at Meta.SO:

[Why can't I vote to close a question that has a bounty on it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284941/why-cant-i-vote-to-close-a-question-that-has-a-bounty-on-it)

And a related question at Meta SE:

[How can we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

To summarize, closing a question prevents further answers, so any bounty would then be unfairly applied to only the first answers, which aren't always as thought out. However, a question can still be closed, but it needs to be done by a moderator. Flag the question, and the moderator has the ability to refund the bounty and close the question.